# Changing the keybindings for virtual terminals in Raspbian Lite

Tags: linux, terminal, raspbian, key-bindings, tty

When using a virtual terminal (TTY) on Linux, there are certain keybindings that are redundant on modern keyboards. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> do the same thing (Linefeed).

I would like keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd> to retain their current mapping, freeing up stuff like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for something else.

On Raspbian Lite (basically, Debian), is it possible to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to something different to <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are five `man` pages you should start with when learning about keymaps:

- See [`keymaps(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/kbd/keymaps.5.en.html) for defining custom keymap files.
- See [`dumpkeys(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/kbd/dumpkeys.1.en.html) to explore the state of the current keymap.
- See [`showkey(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/kbd/showkey.1.en.html) to detect which keycodes your keyboard emits.
- See [`loadkeys(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/kbd/loadkeys.1.en.html) to load a different keymap into the kernel.
- See [`install-keymap(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/console-common/install-keymap.8.en.html) to persistently update the system keymap.

Note: This information relates to the virtual terminals that the kernel provides. Some things are different with X (see [XKB](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/)).